# what is the fastest way to search inside a matrix for min and max alongside of different rows or cols in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

assume that I need to search inside a matrix over rows and cols to find min values, what is the best way to do this?

What I can think of it at the moment is to have two nested vector as follow:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> myData;
```

and search it in this way:

```
// row search on row say 10
int index= std::min_element(myData[10].begin(), myData[10].end()) - myData[10].begin();
```

but for searching on cols, I need to write a for loop to do the search.

```
 // col search say on col 20
 float min_value=10000000;  / assuming values in table are less than this value
 int min_index=-1;
 for(int i=0;i<myData.size();++i)
 {
       if(myData[i][20] <min_value)
       {
            min_value=myData[i][20];
            min_index=i;
        }
  }
```

Is there any better way to do this? I also have access to OpenCV.

Comment: Is your matrix going to be dynamically changing or will it be static?

Comment: The size is known when I want to calculate the min, but the size in not known during compilation.

Comment: The fastest will be to allocate your matrix as one contiguous vector and iterate it sequentially. If the the size is fixed at construction time, that is what to do.

Comment: @Alex that would give me the global min, but I need min alongside of each row or col.

Comment: I meant are the values going to be changing dynamically

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `minMaxLoc` with range/roi, we can use `cv::reduce`([1](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce)) for row/column wise minimum/maximum. Sample below.

```
unsigned char data[4][2] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
Mat img(4, 2, CV_8UC1, data) ;

Mat rowMinImg;
int singleCoumnResult = 1;
cv::reduce(img, rowMinImg, singleCoumnResult, CV_REDUCE_MIN );

//Mat colMinImg;
//int singleRowResult = 0;
//cv::reduce(img, colMinImg, singleRowResult, CV_REDUCE_MIN );
```

A quick look into implementation of cv::reduce([2](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L3250)), shows it is a simple for loop to find min/max values. So, if you have your data already in an OpenCV `Mat`, I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As the elements of your structure are going to be changing, the best option you have is to implement Range minimum query([RMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query)) using [binary index trees](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/)(a.k.a Fenwick trees). I suggest you keep one such tree for each row and for each column. You can also implement a tree of such trees if you want to support a query for a submatrix of the original matrix. The solution I propose will require `O(N * M )` additional memory where N and M are the dimensions of the matrix. It will also support query and update with complexity `O(log(N) + log(M))`.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a y solution that uses cv::Mat and be simple to use and implement?

Comment: I don't know of such solution and I've never used cv::Mat

Answer (score 2):

If you have an OpenCV Mat, you can use [minMaxLoc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc):

```
void minMaxLoc(InputArray src, double* minVal, double* maxVal=0, 
    Point* minLoc=0, Point* maxLoc=0, InputArray mask=noArray())
```

The return values `minVal/maxVal` contain the actual values while `minLoc/maxLoc` are the coordinates of the min/max (the first occurrence if there are multiple).

Obviously, if you pass the entire matrix you'll get the global min/max, but you can also just pass a single row or column.

For a matrix `C` you can find the min/max for column `n` using [Mat::col](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-col)

```
minMaxLoc(C.col(n), &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
```

or for row `m` using [Mat::row](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-row)

```
minMaxLoc(C.row(m), &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
```

Both `Mat::col` and `Mat::row` are `O(1)` operations in that they don't copy any data, but I haven't done any benchmarks to determine how fast their column iteration is.

Comment: This give the min/max for the whole matrix, but I am interested in min/max alongside of a specific row/col.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your use of the word "alongside" in this context.

Comment: Okay, after reading through some of the other answers, it appears you may be looking for the min/max for a given row or column. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While this may be more complicated than you would like, it could be possible to subclass the [iterator base class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/). There is a simple example there. You would redefine the operators to traverse the column instead. That way, you could pass them into min_element just like the row iterators.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to be able to find minimum and maximum values (and locations) of a given matrix:

1. globally
2. in a single row, and,
3. in a single column

Then the following [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) may help you. Let's first look at the output:

```
mat = 
[75, 97, 66, 95, 15, 22;
 24, 21, 71, 72, 34, 66;
 21, 69, 88, 72, 64, 1;
 26, 47, 26, 40, 95, 24;
 70, 37, 9, 83, 16, 83]

global min =   1 @ [5, 2]
global max =  97 @ [1, 0]

Row 0 min =  15 @ [4, 0] max =  97 @ [1, 0]
Row 1 min =  21 @ [1, 1] max =  72 @ [3, 1]
Row 2 min =   1 @ [5, 2] max =  88 @ [2, 2]
Row 3 min =  24 @ [5, 3] max =  95 @ [4, 3]
Row 4 min =   9 @ [2, 4] max =  83 @ [3, 4]

Col 0 min =  21 @ [0, 2] max =  75 @ [0, 0]
Col 1 min =  21 @ [1, 1] max =  97 @ [1, 0]
Col 2 min =   9 @ [2, 4] max =  88 @ [2, 2]
Col 3 min =  40 @ [3, 3] max =  95 @ [3, 0]
Col 4 min =  15 @ [4, 0] max =  95 @ [4, 3]
Col 5 min =   1 @ [5, 2] max =  83 @ [5, 4]
```

And the corresponding code (which you said is OK to use OpenCV):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace {

template <typename T>
std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > findMinMaxLoc( cv::Mat_<T> & mat )
{
    double ignored1, ignored2;
    std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > mmloc;
    cv::minMaxLoc( mat, &ignored1, &ignored2, &(mmloc.first), &(mmloc.second) );

    return mmloc;
}

template <typename T>
std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > minMaxLocRow( cv::Mat_<T> & mat, int row )
{
    cv::Rect roi( 0, row, mat.size().width, 1 );
    cv::Mat_<T> matRow = mat( roi );

    std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > mmloc = findMinMaxLoc( matRow );
    mmloc.first.y  = row;
    mmloc.second.y = row;

    return mmloc;
}

template <typename T>
std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > minMaxLocCol( cv::Mat_<T> & mat, int col )
{
    cv::Rect roi( col, 0, 1, mat.size().height  );
    cv::Mat_<T> matCol = mat( roi );

    std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > mmloc = findMinMaxLoc( matCol );
    mmloc.first.x  = col;
    mmloc.second.x = col;

    return mmloc;
}

} // namespace

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    // Generate a matrix filled with random data.
    cv::Size size( 6, 5 );
    cv::Mat1i mat( size ); // Or cv::Mat1b, cv::Mat3f, etc.
    cv::RNG rng( cv::getCPUTickCount() );

    rng.fill( mat, cv::RNG::UNIFORM, 0, 100 );

    std::cout << "mat = " << std::endl << mat << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Find the global minimum and maximum.
    std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > mmloc = findMinMaxLoc( mat );

    std::cout << "global min = " << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' );
    std::cout << mat( mmloc.first )  << " @ " << mmloc.first  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "global max = " << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' );
    std::cout << mat( mmloc.second ) << " @ " << mmloc.second << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Row-wise extrema.
    for ( int row = 0; row < size.height; ++row )
    {
        std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > mmloc = minMaxLocRow( mat, row );

        std::cout << "Row " << row;
        std::cout << " min = " << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' );
        std::cout << mat( mmloc.first )  << " @ " << mmloc.first;
        std::cout << " max = " << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' );
        std::cout << mat( mmloc.second ) << " @ " << mmloc.second << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Column-wise extrema.
    for ( int col = 0; col < size.width; ++col )
    {
        std::pair< cv::Point, cv::Point > mmloc = minMaxLocCol( mat, col );

        std::cout << "Col " << col;
        std::cout << " min = " << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' );
        std::cout << mat( mmloc.first )  << " @ " << mmloc.first;
        std::cout << " max = " << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' );
        std::cout << mat( mmloc.second ) << " @ " << mmloc.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe my proposed solution isn't *best way* (which you explicitly asked for), but it's a simple one.